# Audio broadcasting service supporting mobile devices

Tags: android, mobile, audio-streaming, wowza, broadcasting

I'm looking for service which allows to:

- broadcast audio stream from mobile device to some kind of backend infrastructure;
- connect hundreds or thousands of mobile listeners to such stream;
- run dozens of such streams simultanously, started and closed (and paid!) on demand;
- manage streams by backend API

Something like "Wowza on demand" would be great, but it actually requires running own server. Primcast is paid per stream per month and has no API. Are there any better services?

Comment: I am in the process of launching such a service, the AudioPump CDN.  The API and billing however are not finished.  Could you please e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co?  Even if my system will not be ready in time for you, I would love to chat about your project's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are many services that offer this; most are actually aimed at distributing video, but can be used perfectly for audio too. It depends a bit on if there are any specific features you need, like stream protection, pay-per-view (I mean: pay-per-listening), etc.

It also depends on how much you want to do yourselves: StreamZilla, BitGravity, CloudFront, etc. offer you infrastructure and you must do the rest yourself; whereas companies like Livestream and Brightcove offer a complete application.

If you've got some very specific requirements and none of the companies found on the net seems to be a match, send me a PM.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't need any DRM- or PPV-related features, but I do need creating and shutting down live streams on demand via API. Sites focused on video does not meet this requirement... PS: no PM here.